# cant run mysql from terminal on mac -xxamp install

Tags: mysql, macos

I just installed xxamp and the tests say everything works fine, but when I run the command

```
mysql -u root
```

I get `-bash: mysql: command not found`

I am very new and don't know how to get past this. Can't finish my first tutorial without this.

Comment: Bash, the command interpreter (or "shell") that your terminal session is using, is reporting to you that it cannot find the `mysql` binary within its execution path.  One solution would be to invoke the command using the full path instead, e.g. `/path/to/mysql -u root`.  Another would be to add that path to Bash's configuration.

Comment: I only get 'code' -bash: /path/to/mysql: No such file or directory '/code'

Comment: http://www.elated.com/articles/mysql-for-absolute-beginners/
This is the tutorial I followed

Comment: I had intended that you replace `/path/to` with the actual path to the `mysql` binary on your machine.  Apologies if that was unclear.

Comment: Sorry It probably was clear, I'm a beginner. Tried to do the easiest set up, still failing hard.

okay so I typed the actual path to the mysql folder in my XAMPP download,
and am getting "code" 

-bash: /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/mysql: is a directory "/code"

but still the 'code' mysql -u root '/code' is not a command. Do I copy what I typed out into a txt file somewhere?

Comment: It sounds as though you still haven't got the path to the binary, only the path to a directory that happens to be called `mysql`.  I'm afraid I don't know XAMPP at all, so can't suggest where the binary might be found—though from a quick browse of their website it seems they might intend for you to use the web-based PhpMyAdmin at http://localhost instead of the command line tool?

Comment: Thank you very much anyway, I appreciate the speedy response!

Sounds like that could be it, every tutorial on youtube shows the commands I put in working out of the box.

everything on the download works flawlessly except terminal commands...fishy but could be fine. I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found a solution that works for me.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
mysql -u root
```

Make sure you have the server running (Manager-osx > Manage servers Tab > Start All) before you enter code!!

Here's where I found the answer: http://data.agaric.com/command-line-mysql-not-working-xampp

I'm sorry if this is a half assed solution but I'm just a beginner (probably like you are). Keep trying and I hope this helps someone.